# Why does my function manage to convert binary to decimal on its own, but not when called in another function?

Tags: c, function, binary

I'm writing a program that calls upon a function applyS() which calls upon a function binaryToDecimal() which converts a char[] filled with 1s and 0s into an integer.
binaryToDecimal() works when i test it on its own.
The char[] which it gets in applyS() is properly filled with the 1s and 0s it should have.
Still, binaryToDecimal() outputs only 0s. Only in the first conversion it outputs a 2, which is still incorrect.

binaryToDecimal() looks like this.:

```
void binaryToDecimal(char binary[], int *decimal, int binLength)
{
*decimal = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < binLength; i++)
{
    int currentPos = binLength - i - 1;
    if (binary[currentPos] == 0 || binary[currentPos] == 1)
    {
        *decimal += binary[currentPos]*pow(2,i);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Illegal input. Can't convert to decimal.");
    }
}
}
```

applyS() looks like this:

```
void applyS(char sTable[][16], char inputBlock[], char outputBlock[])
{
char splitBefore[8][6];
char splitAfter[8][4];

splitForS(inputBlock, splitBefore);

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    int rowArray[2];
    int row;
    int columnArray[4];
    int column;
    int newBlockDecimal;

    rowArray[0] = splitBefore[i][0];
    rowArray[1] = splitBefore[i][5];
    columnArray[0] = splitBefore[i][1];
    columnArray[1] = splitBefore[i][2];
    columnArray[2] = splitBefore[i][3];
    columnArray[3] = splitBefore[i][4];

    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", rowArray[j]);
    }
    printf(" ");
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", columnArray[j]);
    }

    binaryToDecimal(rowArray, &row, 2);

    printf("\t%d ", row);

    binaryToDecimal(columnArray, &column, 4);

    printf("%d ", column);
    printf("\n");

    /*newBlockDecimal = sTable[row][column];

    decimalToBinary(newBlockDecimal, splitAfter[i], 4);*/
}
joinAfterS(splitAfter, outputBlock);
}
```

My output is this:
[image]

Comment: Please make two [mre]s, one for "works" one for "fails".

Comment: A demonstration of the failure is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for helping, I found the mistake.
In applyS() rowArray[] and charArray[] are integer arrays, they should be character arrays.